# sum in case vs case in sum in SQL server ?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any difference between writing :

```
select
...,
mySum= CASE 
           WHEN i  IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE  SUM(i) 
       END  
...
```

vs

```
select
...,
mySum=  SUM( CASE WHEN i IS NULL THEN 0  ELSE i
             END
           ) 
...
```

Or is it just 100% the same  ( *logically and traps...*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my test data, I get the same results returned, and near identical execution plans:

[image]

All the same costs, just two operations reversed.

Answer (score 1):

I think logically there is no difference. But I think you don't need to check for null in this case as [aggregate functions ignore nulls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

BTW, You can simplify `case` with a `isnull` as follows. (**Edit:** mistakenly added `sum(isnull(i,0))` changed to `Isnull(sum(i),0)`)

```
select Col1, Isnull(sum(i),0) as mySum
from yourTable
group by Col1
```

Comment: isnull is slower then is null. :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: `is null` not alone it is inside a `case`. do you have an article or something to read on that?